# branch.io no longer auto-redirects with a custom deepview

Tags: branch.io

We're creating a link through the branch.io API using the following data attributes: 
 `$desktop_url`, `token`, and `$og_image_url`.

When we open up the URL on an iOS device it loads a branch.io default deep view and automatically initiates the redirect to the app store.

When we clone the "Branch Default Passive Template" to create our own template, then proceed with the same steps above, it no longer initiates the automatic redirect to the app store.

Disabling the deep views restores the previous behavior.

I've tried passing configuring `$ios_passive_deepview` with our custom deepview and we get the same non-auto-redirect behavior.

What can we do to restore this auto-redirect behavior with a custom deep view?

(Also, when we provide an invalid path to our custom branch.io domain we get a redirect without any deep view, just a blank page -- not sure how to prevent that).

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by disabling the deep views in the dashboard and then passing in the deep view id into the "$ios_passive_deepview" in the create link api

Answer (score 0):

It appears Branch adds this HTML to the bottom of their pages that auto-redirect. So you can have the same effect by adding it yourself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() {window.top.location = "{{action}}";};</script>
```